# Como pegar o valor de um curl e jogar para outro curl

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho um curl do qual ao executar traz esse valor:

> login: Fernando Pessoa, senha: x2cz

Porém preciso pegar esse valor e jogar para dentro de outro curl para que seja seja logado automaticamente. Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
$output = curl_exec($curl); // resultado da curl anterior a essa

    $obj = json_decode($output,true);

    curk_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.com.br/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($obj))
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $obj); 
    $resultado = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $resultado;
```

Comment: A variável `$output` armazena o valor `login: Fernando Pessoa, senha: x2cz`? Se sim, por que está usando a função `json_decode` numa string que não é um JSON? O intuito seria gerar um array associativo? Descreva como deve ser o POST do segundo curl.

Comment: Na verdade o valor login: Fernando Pessoa, senha: x2cz vem de um outro curl que estou usando, que pega os valores de um json. Porém preciso pegar esse valor e acessar o outro site já logado.

Comment: Seria $output = curl_exec($curl); do curl anterior

Comment: Você precisa esclarecer: 1) qual o conteúdo da variável $obj (verifique com var_dump) e 2) como é o POST que você deseja montar pro segundo pedido (suponho que seja algo como `login=Fernando Pessoa&senha=z2cz`).

Comment: Na verdade acho que nem é necessário o json. Dei um print_r e retornou (abreviei para pegar somente os dados que preciso). {"nome":"Fernando Pessoa","responsavel":[{"email":"fernando.pessoa@siteatual.com.br","mensagem":"Cadastrado com sucesso, senha: bns7"}],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extraia os dados com [regex](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) e depois monte o segundo curl com os parâmetros POST baseados nesses dados:

```
<?php

// Primeiro CURL, obtém dados de login
$output = curl_exec($curl);
$obj = json_decode($output,true);

// extrai a senha
$msg = $obj->responsavel[0]->mensagem;
preg_match("/senha: (.+)/", $msg, $matches);
$senha = $matches[1];


// Faz segundo CURL

$data_string = json_encode(array(
    // Monte o POST conforme for necessário
    // Esse é um exemplo, já que vc não especificou
    'nome' => $obj->nome,
    'senha' => $senha
));

curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.com.br/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
$resultado = curl_exec($curl);
echo $resultado;

?>
```

Comment: Perdoe-me rodorgas. Expressei mal na pergunta. Alterei para ficar mais claro.